# Rails search/checkbox logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create some search function.

I do want users to be able to check checkboxes.

When the form submitted the ID of the companies should be send as params to a given URL.

In my controller i need to create some search action, I just dont know how to params are gonna be.

```
def search
@companyies = Company.find(find all the companies that match the params)'
end
```

How should I create the checkbox loop?
How should I create the search action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the use of check boxes, this might be of some help to you.

A [Railscast by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own search system, you may have better luck using something like [searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) that does most of this for you.

Comment: I am already using it. It is just an important feature that I need